# Acessing element of vector of vectors of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I have a class member:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CellState*> > State;
```

The Cellstate type is a struct:

```
struct CellState
{
bool state;
int x;
int y;
};
```

Using a method of the same class, I want to read/write elements of this structure. All ways I can think of writing it fail. I have many good books on C++ and STL, but can't seem to find the info. I have no idea how to dereference this kind of pointer.

To be clear, I want to do this:

```
State[x][y].state = FALSE;
```

except obviously corrected to account for pointer dereferencing.

Comment: Why would you not have `std::vector<std::vector<CellState> > State;`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth While that is probably better than `std::vector<std::vector<CellState*> > State;`, I am reluctant to believe one needs a list of lists of cell states, as the cells probably form som rectangular block of whatever they model.

Comment: @Baum We appear to have vectors of vectors, not lists of lists.

Comment: I need pointers because the Windows API is expecting pointers in this situation. Also, I'm genuinely curious how to do this either way!

Comment: @NeilButterworth An `std::vector` implements a list of things, despite not being called "list". The fact that it happens to store its elements in contiguous memory does not change that fact.

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted btw?

Comment: @Baum In a language that provides both `list` and `vector` in its Standard Library, I think it important to use the specific and accurate  name for the particular containers we are talking about.

Comment: @NeilButterworth If you insist to reserve the term "list" for containers implemented as linked lists: *While that is probably better than `std::vector<std::vector<CellState*> > State;`, I am reluctant to believe one needs a sequence of sequences of mutable lengths of cell states of mutable length, as the cells probably form some rectangular block of whatever they model.*

Comment: `for( std::vector<CellState*>& cellStates : State ) for( CellState* cellState : cellStates ) { ... }`

Comment: George, was that an answer for me? If so that is a use of "for" that I've never encountered! I'll have to check that out!

Comment: Just added some clarification at the end of my original question

Comment: @DanMoos Yep, they're range based for loops. `State[x][y].state = FALSE;` -> `State[x][y]->state = false;` or `(*State[x][y]).state = false;`

Comment: BAM! It Worked! George both taught me what I needed, and threw in a nugget about for loops that was totally new to me! Rare source of hope that this forum will be a good place for me!

Comment: To the downvoters, I'd love some clarification as to why my "Question does not show any research effort, or is unclear or un-usefull." Seriously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`State[x][y]` is a pointer, so you have to use `->` rather than `.` to access members.  E.g.

```
State[x][y]->state = false;
```

Also note that that is only valid if `x` and `y` are within the bounds of the vectors.  If you know the maximum sizes ahead of time, this could be addressed by declaring the vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CellState *>> State(Width, std::vector<CellState *>(Height));
```

where `Width` is the size in the `x` direction and `Height` is the size in the y direction.

---

On a side note, it is common to index in row, column order rather than column, row order.